# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch' and 'init' - when using useDispach in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

I am trying to make some kind of initialization state in redux, so when the app is loading the app will grab some data from redux (with thunk) and will get the data.

so I need it only once and for that I put [] in the useFffect params ,
but I got the following error:

```
  Line 32:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch' and 'init'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

and I could not insert the useDispatch into the useEffect

```
  const { isReady } = useSelector<AppState, AppProps>((state: AppState) => {
    return {
      isReady: state.appStatus.isReady
    };
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const init = initilizeAction();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(init);
  }, []);
```

Comment: As a workaround you can disable it by adding `// eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `initilizeAction()` to the useEffect, and add dispatch as a dependency (it should not change so it will be triggered only once).

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = initilizeAction();
    dispatch(init);
  }, [dispatch]);
```